# Java Apache Commons Exec Watchdog and Windows cmd.exe issues

Tags: java, windows, watchdog, apache-commons-exec

I am trying to use a watchdog for my program, but it does not work if I used cmd.exe to launching it. Watchdog kills the process if the process is started natively (without cmd.exe), but it does nothing if the program is started with cmd.exe.

Working code example:

```
        CommandLine cmd1 = CommandLine.parse("mysql");

        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(3 * 1000); // wait for 3 sec

        Executor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

        executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);


        try {

            executor.execute(cmd1);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 

        System.out.println("DONE!");
```

Changing the command to this, will block the thread forever ('mysql' waits for user input):

```
CommandLine cmd1 = CommandLine.parse("cmd /C start /wait cmd.exe /C 'mysql'");
```

Do you have any idea, how to solve this problem? The 'mysql' command should be run in a new cmd.exe window.

Comment: I see the same behavior on Linux when trying to run `*.sh` file (the first line is `#!/bin/sh`). Watchdog just doesn't stop this process after timeout! :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by extending ExecuteWatchdog; ie:

```
static class DestroyDescendantsExecutorWatchdog extends ExecuteWatchdog {
    private Process process = null;

    /**
     * Creates a new watchdog with a given timeout.
     *
     * @param timeout the timeout for the process in milliseconds. It must be
     *                greater than 0 or 'INFINITE_TIMEOUT'
     */
    public DestroyDescendantsExecutorWatchdog(long timeout) {
        super(timeout);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to capture and store the process to monitor.
     * @param processToMonitor
     *            the process to monitor. It cannot be {@code null}
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void start(Process processToMonitor) {
        super.start(processToMonitor);
        process = processToMonitor;
    }


    /**
     * Overridden to clean up the process to monitor state as we stop monitoring.
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void stop() {
        super.stop();
        process = null;
    }

    /**
     * Overrides the default behavior to collect the descendants and kill them as well.
     * @param w the watchdog that timed out.
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void timeoutOccured(Watchdog w) {
        // if the process is defined
        if (process != null) {
            boolean isProcessTerminated = true;
            try {
                // We must check if the process was not stopped before being here
                process.exitValue();
            } catch (final IllegalThreadStateException itse) {
                // the process is not terminated, if this is really
                // a timeout and not a manual stop then destroy it.
                if (isWatching()) {
                    isProcessTerminated = false;
                }
            }
            // if we haven't already started terminating the process
            if (!isProcessTerminated) {
                // get all the descendants before you destroy the root process
                Stream<ProcessHandle> descendants = process.toHandle().descendants();
                // now go destroy the root process
                super.timeoutOccured(w);
                // follow up by destroying the descendants as well
                descendants.forEach(descendant -> {
                    try {
                        descendant.destroy();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.warn("pid={};info={}; Could not destroy descendant", descendant.pid(), descendant.info(), e);
                    }
                });
                // no longer watching this process as it's destroyed
                process = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The real magic is destroying the descendants along with the root process.

I have a unit test showing that basically does this:

bash "script.sh"
where script.sh is just a "sleep 5"

Before using ExecuteWatchdog, the ExecuteWatchdog would timeout the process with an exit code of 143, but only after 5 seconds.  After replacing ExecuteWatchdog with DestroyDescendantsExecutorWatchDog with a 5ms timeout, the unit test almost immediately exits with the expected return code of 143.